# Double Convert.ToDecimal control decimal digits

Tags: .net

I am trying to convert a double to a decimal using Convert.ToDecimal function. 
The problem is that somehow .net chooses to omit decimal digits depending on the size of original double variable.

Take the following example:

```
        double d = 2999247013.972682;
        decimal convDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(d);
        decimal realDecimal = 2999247013.972682M;

        Console.WriteLine(d);
        Console.WriteLine(convDecimal);
        Console.WriteLine(realDecimal);
```

Which produces the following output:

```
2999247013,97268  // comments: (actual value 2999247013,972682)
2999247013,97268  // comments: (actual value 2999247013,97268)
2999247013,972682 // comments: (actual value 2999247013,972682)
```

(',' is the decimal separator on current locale)

What i am trying to achieve is to use a Convert.ToDecimal(d) and get the decimal number 2999247013,972682.

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `Decimal` value returned can only have a maximum of 15 signification digits. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a69w9ca0.aspx).

> The [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) value returned by this method contains a maximum of 15
>   significant digits. If the value parameter contains more than 15
>   significant digits, it is rounded using rounding to nearest. The
>   following example illustrates how the Convert.ToDecimal(Double) method
>   uses rounding to nearest to return a [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) value with 15 significant
>   digits.

Therefore, if there are more than 15 significant digits it will be rounded, which is what is happening in your case since the `double` value you're passing has 16 significant digits.

Comment: So as far as i can tell, the problem is that Convert.ToDecimal cannot handle more than 15 significant digits, even though Decimal as a type clearly supports this value.

Comment: The issue isn't that `Decimal` can support more digits, it's that the `Double` value is limited. Decimals are more precise than doubles, so the limiting factor is  the double you're passing into the method.

Comment: OK. Things are starting to make sense now. Thank you for all the info.

Comment: No problem, hope it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(v=VS.71).aspx) double data type in .net has 15-16 digits and I guess in your case it is 15 so it omits the last digit. Why are you using double in the first place?
You can read [double vs decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when) for more information about these types and their usages.